# Is svnserve not strictly required for a local, single-user repo?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnserve

I was reading [the Red Bean book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html) and noticed this paragraph:

> Do not be seduced by the simple idea
>   of having all of your users access a
>   repository directly via file:// URLs.
>   Even if the repository is readily
>   available to everyone via a network
>   share, this is a bad idea. It removes
>   any layers of protection between the
>   users and the repository: users can
>   accidentally (or intentionally)
>   corrupt the repository database, it
>   becomes hard to take the repository
>   offline for inspection or upgrade, and
>   it can lead to a mess of file
>   permission problems (see the section
>   called “Supporting Multiple Repository
>   Access Methods”). Note that this is
>   also one of the reasons we warn
>   against accessing repositories via
>   svn+ssh://  URLs—from a security
>   standpoint, it's effectively the same
>   as local users accessing via file://,
>   and it can entail all the same
>   problems if the administrator isn't
>   careful.

I realized that, since I'm the only one accessing the repository, ever, none of these caveats seem to apply.  Can I safely down `svnserve` then and only ever have to worry about upgrading my TortoiseSVN client, not both the client and the server whenever there's a new version out?

(I've tried it already--just needed to use the Relocate feature to switch from svn:// to file://--but I wanted to make sure something wouldn't be sneaking up on me if I left it this way.)

Comment: BTW if anybody goes to do this, you'll want to Relocate each of your working copies before downing the old service, otherwise it will complain and not switch it over.  (On 1.6 anyway.)

Comment: Also don't uninstall the package `svnserve` came with, because you may still want `svnadmin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  These warnings do not apply if you are the only one ever accessing the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using SVN with Tortoise and Slik Subversion clients using the single-user file:// urls for a couple of years now, with absolutely zero problems. But if you ever, ever think you will need multi-user access, you need to use one of the server access methods - don't be tempted to put a file:// repository on a shared network drive.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem I see is with svn there is a level of indirection between you and the repository so that you maybe able to move a repository without it affecting working copies which you cant using the file url.

i.e if youre repository is in /user/repos and you ran

`svnserve as svnserve --daemon --root /user`

the user would access file using

`svn://localhost/repos` 
if later on you have to use change the repository to now be in /user2 you can just run

`svnserve --daemon --root /user2`

and existing checkout code would still be ok, wheras if using file protocol you would have to relocate your files.